# Format date in <f:selectItem(s) itemLabel> using DateTimeConverter

Tags: jsf, label, converters, selectonemenu, date-formatting

I have a `<h:selectOneMenu>` that has `<f:selectItems>` with `CategoryHistory` objects loaded in it. I only show the `Date date` field as `itemLabel`.
That works but I want to format the date:
I created a converter that extends `javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter` and change the fields in the constructor. But my dates only show in default format :(

**DateAndTimeConverter.java**

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter(value = "dateAndTimeconverter")
@ManagedBean
public class DateAndTimeConverter extends DateTimeConverter implements Converter {

 public DateAndTimeConverter(){  
  this.setDateStyle("short");
 }
```

**xhtml**

```
 <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{admin.categoryHistoryListener}"
    onchange="submit()" value="#{admin.categoryHistory.id}" converter="#{dateAndTimeconverter}">       
  <f:selectItems value="#{admin.categoryHistories}" var="n"
     itemValue="#{n.id}" itemLabel="#{n.date}">
  </f:selectItems>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

It also doesn't work when I try:

```
<h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{admin.categoryHistoryListener}"
    onchange="submit()" value="#{admin.categoryHistory.id}">
  <f:converter converterId="dateAndTimeconverter"/>       
  <f:selectItems value="#{admin.categoryHistories}" var="n"
     itemValue="#{n.id}" itemLabel="#{n.date}">
  </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**CategoryHistory** Has a Date date, and Long id +...

Thank you

Comment: Unrelated to the actual problem: why is the converter declared `@ManagedBean`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the JSF converters only applies on the input **value**, not on the input **label**.

You'll need to solve this other ways. E.g. a getter which uses [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date. Or if your environment supports EL 2.2, simply invoke the converter method directly (you've it as managed bean already):

```
<f:selectItems value="#{admin.categoryHistories}" var="n" itemValue="#{n.id}" 
    itemLabel="#{dateAndTimeconverter.getAsString(facesContext, component, n.date)}">
```

If you happen to use JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org), then you can also use its [`of:formatDate()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Dates) function. E.g.:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{admin.categoryHistories}" var="n" itemValue="#{n.id}" 
    itemLabel="#{of:formatDate(n.date, 'd MMM yyyy')}">
```

Comment: Ouch that hurts... Thanks anyway:)

Comment: I love OmniFaces, JSF is not complete without this great library!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a converter method in your bean, as:

```
public class Admin{
    ...
        public String formatDate(Date fecha, String pattern) {
            return (new SimpleDateFormat(pattern)).format(fecha);
        }
    ...
}
```

And, in your xhtml page inside f:selectItems:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{admin.categoryHistories}" var="n"
               itemValue="#{n.id}" itemLabel="#{admin.formatDate(n.date,'d MMM yyyy')}">
</f:selectItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

> xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{tbMonitoreoController.fechaMonitoreo}">
<f:selectItems value="#{tbMonitoreoController.fechasMonitoreo}" />
```

> Method in tbMonitoreoController

```
public SelectItem[] getFechasMonitoreo(){
    Collection<Date> entities = getEjbFacade().getFechasMonitoreo();
    return JsfUtil.getSelectItemsFechasMonitoreo(entities, true);
}

public static SelectItem[] getSelectItemsFechasMonitoreo(Collection<Date> listDate, boolean selectOne) {
    int size = selectOne ? (listDate.size() + 1) : listDate.size();
    SelectItem[] items = new SelectItem[size];
    int i = 0;

    if (selectOne) {
        items[0] = new SelectItem(null, "---");
        i++;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    for (Date x : listDate) {
        items[i++] = new SelectItem(x, simpleDateFormat.format(x));
    }
    return items;
}
```

[image]